# how to get current branch from TFS postbuild scripts

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've to get current branch name from TFS post build scripts. Based on the branch name, I've to execute some steps. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Classic TFVC or Git version control?

Comment: Hi Vian, Thanks for the reply. I need it in Classic TFS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to solve this in a general case: it depends how one organizes his version control (see graphic).

```
$
|
+--Project1
|   |
|   +--Branch1
|   |
|   +--Branch2
|
+--Project2
   |
   +--App1
   |    |
   |    +--Branch3
   |
   +--App2
        |
        +--Branch4
```

You can apply either one of these techniques:

1. get the path of post-build script (assuming is part of the branch)
2. pass the name of the branch as a Build parameter

To get the path to  in a Batch file use `%p0`, in PowerShell use `$PSScriptRoot`, then you have to parse it and extract the branch portion.

To implement the second option, must [customize the Build template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx) to require the parameter and pass it to the script.

Comment: This would only work if your powershell is under the branch folder. If it is shared then this may not be possible.

Comment: I specified, but I see it is not so clear that I suggested two techniques. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the paths that are configured for this build through the IBuildDetails. You can, however, configure this to pull from multiple builds. You can get the array of paths and as long as you have a consistent folder structure for branches you can pattern match your branch name.

There are a number of variables available out of the box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

Comment: The RunScriptactivity, which launch the scripts, spawn a new process with no knowledge of the running workflow.
So you suggest to pass the information to the script, after collecting data in a custom workflow.

Comment: There are a number of workflow variables available in the script. I have updated with a link to the documentation.